# SQL Case Statement To Increment Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Trying to create a calculated column that would have a value based on the values in four other columns. 
Column 1, Coulmn 2, Column 3, Column 4 could be either Yes or No
The end result in the calculated column, let's say called Progress, should be something along this line:

```
Progress = CASE
WHEN [Column1] = 'Yes' THEN Value+1
WHEN [Column2] = 'Yes' THEN Value+1
WHEN [Column3] = 'Yes' THEN Value+1
WHEN [Column4] = 'Yes' THEN Value+1
ELSE 0 END
```

Hope this makes sense as obviously the syntax for the above is not correct.

Comment: so you want the sum of 'Yes's in those columns?

Comment: Please provide sample data and results to clarify what you really want.

Comment: What is your RDBMS (SQL flavor)?  Is it MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like this is what you're going for.

```
Progress = 
CASE WHEN [Column1] = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN [Column2] = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN [Column3] = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
CASE WHEN [Column4] = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

This will return 0 + 1 for each "Yes".

Comment: That worked! Thanks for the prompt response. Saved me a whole bunch of aggravation and time :-)

Comment: @user1886816 No problem.  Good tip is to always try to encase one and only one value within a single CASE statement.  4 columns = 4 cases.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  COALESCE(SUM(CASE val WHEN 'yes' THEN 1 END), 0)
        FROM    (VALUES (NULL)) q(v)
        UNPIVOT
                (
                val FOR col IN
                (column1, column2, column3, column4)
                ) c
        ) q (progress)
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1e27d/5).